# Use linear interpolation to fill up pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have given a pandas dataset containing two columns: Interpolated (1/0) and Output (integer).

I want to replace the values for Output where Interpolated =  1 with linear interpolated values. I know I can get these interpolated values by calculating the slope between two actual values and just adding the slope * 0.5 to the first of the two values (if there is only one interpolated value between 2 actual values).

I also know how to replace these values using:

```
mask = new_df.Interpoliert == 1
new_df.loc[mask, 'Output'] = ...
```

But I am not sure how to apply my interpolation here. I would have to know the last and next actual value and how far the distance to the current value is, but I haven't found a way to get that information.

Is there a way to do this using pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to use `numpy.interp` or `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, put the results in a temporary Series, then copy the values from the Series into `Output` for those rows where `Interpolated == 1`.

Comment: I noticed that there doesn't seem to be a `x` coordinate set of values, just `y` values, so I assume `x` is just a simple integer incremental list, something like `np.arange(len(df)`.